# Configure Eclipse to run perl on linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, perl, epic

i'm kinda all-eclipse so i'm trying to use Eclipse to execute perl scripts. On Windows i was able to configure everyting fine within a minute, so i had hole perl in one tool (Eclipse).

How to configure External tool within Eclipse to run perl scripts on linux? It seem's i've got problems with 'Location' and 'Arguments' within definition of a new configuration for external tool.

It works only if i put '/something/test.pl' in Location with empty Arguments field. But this works only for 1 file. Kinda now what i'm going for...

Does some1 manage to configure Eclipse to run perl on linux? If so, i'm humble asking you to share the solution :)

Here's how it looks and what i'm getting:
http://s21.postimg.org/g2rnzvqs7/eclipse1.png
http://s11.postimg.org/y4klufjo3/eclipse2.png

Thx in advance to all of you :)

Comment: Install the perl EPIC from `http://www.epic-ide.org/`. I did that and created a perl project and a perl file in it. I am able to run that script without any hassle.

Comment: Ok, i see my mistake... i've tried to configure external perl while local perl can be used. Everything works perfect now, when i'm not trying to do overkill :D